# elsarticle table and figure caption

Tags: tables, floats, captions, lyx, elsarticle

I want to change the caption of `elsarticle` in LyX for table to be

[image]

and for figures to be

[image]

Mine is the following:

I use the `caption` package in document preamble

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small]{caption}
```

but I get large word **Table** in bold

and **figure** not **fig.** as required and also after figure there is a new line which is not required

here is mine
[image]

and figure is here

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\captionsetup` to provide different options for `table` and `figure`:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A test table caption}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A test figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should take into account the warning you get from using `caption` with `elsarticle` class:

> Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package)
>   detected, (caption)                usage of the caption package is not
>   recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: I still have small problem , i want to minimize the font of word Table 1 and Fig. 1. to be like caption, at my pdf caption has smaller size than Table and Fig

Comment: I put caption package in folder of elsarticle.lyx , I think this is right?

Comment: @mero please explain exactly what size do you want and for what parts (the label, the label and the caption text)?

Comment: i found it thanks so much , i've this problem from weeks , thanks again and again :) \usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=footnotesize]{caption} 
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig,labelsep=period} 
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline}

Comment: Just a short note that the warning will go away when updating to the current version 3.3 of the `caption` package (which I just have released and which is adapted to the elsarticle document class now.)